# Dynamic linking between crates

Tags: rust

The state of dynamic linking in rust is very confusing to me currently. I can only find old sources that say rust doesn't support dynamic linking, yet I know multiple libraries that do dynamic linking (ex `bevy_dylib`). 
Is it currently possible to create a `bin` crate and a `lib` crate, and link the `bin` to the `lib` at runtime using `dylib` or `rlib`? 
Something like

```rust
// lib.rs
fn hi() {
   println!("hi");
}


// main.rs
fn main() {
   // whatever to link to lib.rs/lib.so
   link("./lib.so");
   hi();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, the [reference page on linkage](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html) seems pretty clear.

Comment: I've looked through that but it doesn't really say if and how the above is possible, it just lists what rust can be compiled too and stuff about linking to C.

Comment: "--crate-type=dylib, #![crate_type = "dylib"] - A dynamic Rust library will be produced. This is different from the lib output type in that this forces dynamic library generation. The resulting dynamic library can be used as a dependency for other libraries and/or executables. This output type will create *.so files on Linux, *.dylib files on macOS, and *.dll files on Windows" clearly says it's possible, you use the type `dylib`

Comment: I know how to make a `dylib`, but how do I actually link to it from the main binary?

Comment: "use [it] as a dependency" in Cargo.toml `[dependencies] yourcrate = {path = "whatever", version = "*" }` the same as for a static library

Answer (score 7):

To link dynamically instead of statically the only thing you have to change is the crate type of your library from the default to `dylib`:

Generate a library:

```bash
cargo new --lib dy-lib
```

Add the type in `dy-lib/Cargo.toml` everything else can stay unchanged:

```ini
[lib]
crate-type = ["dylib"]
```

Generate a binary and add library as dependency:

```bash
cargo new dy-bin
cd dy-bin
cargo add dy-lib --path ../dy-lib
```

Replace the contents of `dy-bin/src/main.rs` with something that uses the library:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{}", dy_lib::add(1, 2));
}
```

build the binary

```bash
cargo build # or cargo run, ...
```

The binary is now dynamically linked to our dynamic library as can be seen by for example `readelf` on linux:

```bash
$ readelf -d target/debug/dy-bin

Dynamic section at offset 0x2d70 contains 30 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdy_lib.so]
...
```

And if you remove it there will be a runtime error:

```bash
$ rm target/debug/libdy_lib.so
$ target/debug/dy-bin
target/debug/dy-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libdy_lib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Note that Rust ABI is not stable, so one would better use `cdylib` instead of `dylib` and make all necessary functions `extern "C"`.

Comment: I followed this template trying to cross compile a binary/library couple for ARM platform, but when I run the bin in the board I get ./dy-bin: symbol lookup error: ./dy-bin: undefined symbol: _ZN6dy_lib3add17hdf2afda1776ef745E